# Creating checkboxes in dompdf

Tags: html, input, checkbox, dompdf

Is it possible to use checkbox elements (along with the checked property) when converting HTML to PDF using dompdf?

I'm using 0.6.3 beta, and some initial tests are not proving successful:

```
<p>Checkboxes:
<p><input type=checkbox name=on checked> ON
<p><input type=checkbox name=off> OFF
```

Results in:

```
Checkboxes:
ON
OFF
```

The same behavior is confirmed in dompdf 0.5.1 and 0.5.2.

I am using the checkboxes for display purposes only.  Any client entered data is processed before passing data back to dompdf.  The stakeholder is firm about their request for the PDF to contain checkboxes (some checked, some not depending on pre-processed user input).

Is dompdf able to handle checkboxes (and other input elements), if so how should they be coded in the source HTML?

Comment: Can you use an image instead?

Comment: I was able to use images in 0.5.2, but am getting an infinite loop with 0.6.3 beta with the same source code.  RHEL 5.4, PHP 5.3.16.

Comment: Are you getting an infinite loop only when using the images?

Comment: Only on the full form.  I can break out sections of the form (containing images) and the PDF is generated.   Each section is a separate table, and is stacked one after the next.

Comment: If you have any table cell within a section that is larger than a page then you're likely running into the following issue: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=91

Comment: Think that might be the source of my woes.  0.6.3 beta appears to render images differently from 0.5.x -- embedded images are drawn much larger with the beta version, and that may be widening the cell content enough to trigger Issue 91.  Will respond back when I learn more.

Comment: Cell width was the culprit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I committed [r500](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/detail?r=500) today, which permits to display form elements.

You can grab it by checking out the SVN trunk.