# How to add clickable checkboxes in dompdf?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Is it possible to insert clickable checkboxes into PDFs with dompdf? If so, how?

What I mean by 'clickable' is that in the PDF itself, when the user clicks on the checkbox, the checkbox should then become ticked or unticked (depending on its previous state).
I've tried . The checkbox does appear in the PDF but it is static - you cannot interact with it.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating checkboxes in dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074327/creating-checkboxes-in-dompdf)

Comment: @frank no, that answer seems to just cover how to display static inputs, not how to display inputs that can actually be changed in the PDF (which is what I want)